Ошибка при чтении даты в python AIOGRAM
Пишу бота на aiogram, в котором при нажатии кнопки "узнать расписание по дате" бот спрашивает дату в формате ДД-ММ-ГГГГ, проверяет ее на правильность ввода, переводит в день недели формата isoweekday(), записывая в переменную, и далее по полученному дню недели, записанного в переменную poluch, показывает сообщение о выборе класса. На выходе выдает ошибку ValueError: time data 'Узнать расписание по дате' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y' Как можно исправить?
#Любая дата
@router.message(F.text == 'Узнать расписание по дате')
async def vvod_dati(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Введите дату в формате ДД-ММ-ГГГГ')
    global datestr
    datestr = message.text
    global poluch
    poluch = DT.datetime.strptime(datestr, '%d-%m-%Y').isoweekday()

    try:
        date = parse(datestr)
        await message.answer(message.chat.id, 'Спасибо, дата введена')   
    except ValueError:
        await message.answer(message.chat.id, 'Не верный формат даты, необходимо ДД-ММ-ГГГГ')

async def change_classdat(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Выберите свой класс", reply_markup=app.Keyboards.inlinedat)


У вас в сообщении об ошибке все написано. Там написано, что вы пытаетесь превратить в дату строку "Узнать расписание по дате", а не то что ввел пользователь. Значит message.text содержит именно эту сроку. А где искать то что вводит пользователь посмотрите в документации на aiogram

И global уберите. вам тут глобальные переменные явно не нужны (они вообще нужны в крайне редких случаях). Так вы можете данные от разных пользователей перепутать
